# What's next this step iphone login with php webservice

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, web-services, authentication

i developing an iphone app with login to mysql db by php api , after i checking the authentication of username and password that will redirect to the home screen.

The problem that i need to pass the user id to the home screen to fetch over API an other data with the logged in user, So how can i do that .. if anybody has an experience in that issue please help..

this code about the login process after checking the validity of user over PHP API:

```
if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"OK"] ){
    Home *home = [[[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    home.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:home animated:YES];
    [serverOutputLabel release];
} else {
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Login"
    message:@"Username or Password Incorrect"
    delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    serverOutputLabel.text=serverOutput;
    [alertsuccess show];
    [alertsuccess release];
    [serverOutputLabel release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store user id in `NSUSerDefautls` and if its a valid your keep them save in `NSUserDefaults` otherwise clean them if it's an invalid user.

So next time when you want to send request to server, get User id from `NSUserDefaults` and append it to api.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:YOUR_USER_ID forKey:@"UserId"];
```

to get user id from defaults.

```
 NSString *userId = [defaults objectForKey:@"UserId"];
```

Also clear the defaults when user log out and on authentication failure.

```
[defaults setObject:@"" forKey:@"UserId"];
```

also see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: thanks that is very useful for me , I founded the solution in NSUserDefaults